# pcb etching: chemical method or milling

Tags: pcb, etching

i'am actually intending to install a small pcb production process (100 pieces per day) 
and i am still hesitating on the etching method: chemical or with a milling machine !!
I would prefer a cnc machine but would it produce industrial standard pcb's ??
And do you know some good manufacturers

Comment: Good manufacturers of what? There are thousands of PCB manufacturers in China, many of them are good. And thousands more outside of China. Just about every single one of them can produce a better board than an expensive milling machine such as LPKF.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany not just a better board than a router, but one with nice-to-haves if not necessities like solder mask, overlay, plated vias, and different finishes. Most importantly though: repeatability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say etching, should be cheaper as well.  I'd only consider milling if I wanted to make prototypes in my office right that minute.  I remember that the cost of a professional grade pcb milling machine was pretty expensive.  I've seen some 3d printer mods that could be cheaper.

If you're worried about handling chemicals you'll have to anyway for the via process unless your boards don't require vias.

You should be able to do more boards per unit of time in an etching tank then a single milling machine I think.  That means etching

Also unless this is just for you, I personally wouldn't order a board from someone milling them.

Comment: And 100 units a day is 5 minutes per board for milling - that's mighty fast. I'd even say unreasonably fast, particularly when you include the time required for loading and unloading boards.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Not just unreasonably fast, impossibly fast.  I have access to an LPKF S103; it's a good prototyping tool, but a five minute board would be tiny and have next to nothing on it.  Any useful double-sided board takes around an hour.